# Using libGDX in Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android

I successfully imported a "testgame" project into Android Studio using the build.gradle in the root directory of where libGDX populated the project files.

Within the root directory, I noticed there is an "android" sub-directory that also has a build.gradle file and includes other sub-directories for different files that are specific to android. The different files include assets, libs, etc.

When I try to import that build.gradle file into Android Studio, it does not display the proper class and manifest files needed for the game.

I tried to search for what a successful import should look like in Android Studio, but had no luck.

Has anyone successfully used the libGDX framework within Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I tested a demo on libGDX on Android Studio 1.0.2 and it worked, the following link leads to my screenshot showing the version of my AS and the output from an emulator

https://www.facebook.com/yaten.Notes.Android/photos/a.438504762964810.1073741827.438486782966608/438689702946316/?type=1&theater

Sorry, can't post screenshot directly, I need 10 rep to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were right the first time, but then tried to import another file.

The build.grade file in the root of the project is the correct file to select when importing into Android Studio.

This is in line with [the official wiki instructions](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA), as Android Studio (at least through the current 1.1.0) is built on top of Intellij.

Once you've imported that project you should automatically be able to run on Android, as a configuration will have already been created.

It is incorrect to import any of the other build.gradle files, such as the one in the android directory that you tried to load.